# implementation of hash table

Tags: c++, hash

i have following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string.h>
#include <hash_map>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;
struct Equal
{

    bool operator()(const char *s1,const char *s2)const
        {
            return std::strcmp(s1,s2)==0;
        }

};
    typedef std::hash_multimap<const char*,int,hash<const char*>,Equal>map_type;
    void lookup(const map_type&Map,const char *str){
        cout<<str<<":";
        pair<map_type::const_iterator ,map_type::const_iterator>p=Map.equal_range(str);
        for (map_type::const_iterator i=p.first;i!=p.second;++i)
            cout << (*i).second<<" ";



    }
int maain(){

    map_type m;
    m.insert(map_type::value_type("H", 1));
 m.insert(map_type::value_type("H", 2));
 m.insert(map_type::value_type("C", 12));
  m.insert(map_type::value_type("C", 13));
  m.insert(map_type::value_type("O", 16));
  m.insert(map_type::value_type("O", 17));
  m.insert(map_type::value_type("O", 18));
  m.insert(map_type::value_type("I", 127));
  lookup(M,"I");
  lookup(M,"0");
  lookup(M,"Rn");


    return 0;
}
```

but here is errors

```
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\hash_map(26): error C2903: 'rebind' : symbol is neither a class template nor a function template
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xhash(170) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Hmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Tr,_Alloc,_Mfl>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=const char *,
1>              _Ty=int,
1>              _Tr=std::hash<const char *>,
1>              _Alloc=Equal,
1>              _Mfl=true
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\hash_map(273) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Hash<_Traits>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Traits=std::_Hmap_traits<const char *,int,std::hash<const char *>,Equal,true>
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\7\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hash_tables\hash_tables\hash_tables.cpp(22) : see reference to class template instantiation 'stdext::hash_multimap<_Kty,_Ty,_Tr,_Alloc>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=const char *,
1>              _Ty=int,
1>              _Tr=std::hash<const char *>,
1>              _Alloc=Equal
1>          ]
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\hash_map(26): error C2039: 'rebind' : is not a member of 'Equal'
1>          c:\users\7\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hash_tables\hash_tables\hash_tables.cpp(11) : see declaration of 'Equal'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\hash_map(26): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\hash_map(26): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\hash_map(26): error C2039: 'other' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\hash_map(27): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xhash(180): error C2039: 'bucket_size' : is not a member of 'std::hash<_Kty>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=const char *
1>          ]
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xhash(180): error C2065: 'bucket_size' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xhash(184): error C2039: 'allocator_type' : is not a member of 'std::_Hmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Tr,_Alloc,_Mfl>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=const char *,
1>              _Ty=int,
1>              _Tr=std::hash<const char *>,
1>              _Alloc=Equal,
1>              _Mfl=true
1>          ]
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xhash(184): error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'allocator_type'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xhash(184): error C2065: 'allocator_type' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xhash(186): error C2955: 'std::list' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\list(579) : see declaration of 'std::list'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xhash(187): error C2955: 'std::list' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\list(579) : see declaration of 'std::list'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xhash(188): error C2955: 'std::list' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\list(579) : see declaration of 'std::list'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xhash(189): error C2955: 'std::list' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\list(579) : see declaration of 'std::list'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xhash(190): error C2955: 'std::list' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\list(579) : see declaration of 'std::list'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xhash(191): error C2955: 'std::list' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\list(579) : see declaration of 'std::list'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xhash(192): error C2955: 'std::list' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\list(579) : see declaration of 'std::list'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xhash(193): error C2955: 'std::list' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\list(579) : see declaration of 'std::list'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xhash(197): error C2955: 'std::list' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\list(579) : see declaration of 'std::list'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xhash(198): error C2955: 'std::list' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\list(579) : see declaration of 'std::list'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xhash(198): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'iterator'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xhash(198): error C3254: 'std::_Hash<_Traits>' : class contains explicit override 'type' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Traits=std::_Hmap_traits<const char *,int,std::hash<const char *>,Equal,true>
1>          ]
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xhash(198): error C2838: 'type' : illegal qualified name in member declaration
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xhash(198): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xhash(198): error C2208: 'std::iterator' : no members defined using this type
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xhash(198): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.96
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

please help

Comment: `int maain(){` isn't going to help much

Comment: are not you reincarnation of guy with nick david-dav... i don't remember exactly?

Comment: I strongly recommend you get the hash table code working with integers.  After the fundamentals work, then convert to a template.

Comment: not reading this, closing as too localized, downvoting

Answer (score 5):

You have to look at each complier error and fix them one at a time.  We can't take a file of code and fix each error.  Learning to live and even on occasion love the abusive spouse that is your complier is part of the process.

Comment: Especially when multiple lines of seemingly indecipherable and unrelated errors result from a single missing semicolon. :-)

Comment: Deciphering template errors is an aquired skill and the poster seems to be new to C++. At least, pointing out the relevant parts of the error message might help him/her out for the next compiler vomit he/she comes accross!

Answer (score 4):

All your errors seem related to the fact that you're not passing the right template arguments to `hash_multimap`. Take a look at [`hash_multimap`'s documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ewecebk%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). The last parameter, Èqual` should be the allocator, not a function object, check out the 1st error:

> c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\hash_map(26): error C2903: 'rebind' : symbol is neither a class template nor a function template
>            c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xhash(170) : see reference to **class template instantiation** 'std::_Hmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Tr,_Alloc,_Mfl>' being compiled
>            **with**
>            [
>                _Kty=const char *,
>                _Ty=int,
>                _Tr=std::hash,
>                **_Alloc=Equal**,
>                _Mfl=true
>            ]

**Edit**:

If you've looked at [SGI's `hash_multimap` documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_multimap.html), you'll notice that the `hash_map` and `hash_multimap` classes are different between vendors because they are **not** standard. The next version of the standard comprises standard hashed containers. In the mean time, well, you'll have to write non portable code!